# Two forms in the same page with one submit button

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have a form link to a search nav formExterne

[image]

When the User use the search bar, there are of course only the results for "Externe" that appear on the correct tab of the datatable

[image]

If I replace "formExterne" with my other form "formInterne" only results for "Interne" appear. What I want is one form link to the search nav that display when submit the results at the same time for each category ("Externe" and "Interne") in each tab of the datatable. Is this possible ? Thanks in advance.

This is my formExterne in my index.html.twig

```
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}



{% block body %}
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav col s12">

  <div class="container bg-container form-scroller">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="titre-top">
        <span class="contact2-form-title">
          RECHERCHE DE CORRESPONDANTS MÉDICAUX
        </span>
      </div id="form_search">
      {{ form_start(formExterne,{'action' : path('rechercher')}) }}

      
      <ul class="collapsible">
        <li class="active">
          <div class="collapsible-header white-text center-align"><i class="material-icons">person</i><p class="label_sidenav">Identité</p> <p class="id">(<span id="showid"></span>/3)</p></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice0">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medNom, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'idCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medNom">Nom</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice1">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medPren, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'idCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medPren">Prénom</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice2">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.mednomEp, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'idCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_mednomEp">Nom marital</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header white-text"><i class="material-icons">work</i><p class="label_sidenav">Renseignements</p><p class="re">(<span id="showre"></span>/5)</p></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice3">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medcpltTitre, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' : 'reCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medcpltTitre">Complément Titre</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice4">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medSpec, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' : 'reCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medSpec">Spécialité</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 taille" id="choice5">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.rpps, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'maxlength':'11', 'pattern' : '[0-9]{11}', 'onchange' :'reCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_rpps">RPPS</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 taille" id="choice6">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.adresseApicrypt, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'reCompleted()', 'pattern' : "[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}"}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_adresseApicrypt">Adresse Électronique Sécurisée</label>
            </div>
            <div class="date col s12 taille" id="choice7">
              <label id="labelDate" for="corr_med_ext_gdatecreation">Date de Création</label>
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.gdatecreation, {'attr': {'class':'date', 'type':'date', 'onchange' :'reCompleted()'}}) }}

            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="collapsible-header white-text"><i class="material-icons">location_on</i><p class="label_sidenav">Adresse</p><p class="adr">(<span id="showad"></span>/3)</p></div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice8">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medadrL1, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'adCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medadrL1">Adresse</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12" id="choice9">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medadrCo, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'adCompleted()'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medadrCo">Commune</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 taille" id="choice10">
              {{ form_widget(formExterne.medadrCp, {'attr': {'class': 'validate', 'onchange' :'adCompleted()', 'pattern' : '[0-9]{4,5}','maxlength':'5'}}) }}
              <label for="corr_med_ext_medadrCp">Code Postal</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="checking">
        <button class="ok-btn sidenav-close" id="toggle" type="submit" name="action" data-target="slide-out"
          data-url='path{{'rechercher'}}'>VALIDER</button>
        {{ form_end(formExterne) }}       
        <button class="ok-btn" id="reset" type="reset">REINITIALISER</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="version">Version {{version}}</p>
</ul>


<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="bouton-sidenav">
    <a id="recherche" href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><img src="/img/loupe-white.png"
        alt="">Rechercher</a>
  </div>
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    <!--Modal trigger-->
    {% if int is empty or ext is empty and int!='defaut' %}
    <div id="addIcon" class="bouton-ajouter">
      <a class="popup" data-target="{{ path('ajouter')}}" href="#modal"><img src="/img/icon-add.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    {% if int is empty or ext is empty and int!='defaut' %}
    <div id="toolIcon" class="bouton-tool">
      <a id="gestion" class="popup" data-target="{{path('gestion')}}" href="#modal" ><img src="/img/tool-icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <!--<div class="logo-emplacement"><img class="logo" src="img/logogris.png" alt=""></div>-->
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
  <a class='profil dropdown-trigger' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'><img src="/img/icon.png" alt="" width="30"></a>
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content deco'>
    <li>
      <a href="{{path('logout')}}">
        <i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i>Déconnexion</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="logo-emplacement center container">
  <img src="img/logo3.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>





<!--TABLEAU-->
{% if int =='defaut' or (int is empty and ext is empty and recherche == false)%}

<main style="display:block">
  <div id="parent" class="col s8 m12 l12">
    <div class="placement-illu"><img class="illu" src="/img/illu-recherche.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div id="parent" class="col s8 m12 l12">
    <div class="logo-chu"><img class="logo-chu" src="/img/logo-chu.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</footer>

{% elseif int is empty and ext is empty and recherche == true %}
<main>
  <div id="parent" class="col s8 m12 l12">
    <div class="placement-illu"><img class="illu" src="/img/illu-recherche.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal1" class="modal small_popup">
    <div id="modal-content" class="modal-content-popup ">
      <div id='div_table'>
        <div class="row modal-header">
          <a class="js-modal-close modal-close close-popup">X</a>
          <i style='' class="large material-icons">error</i>
        </div>
        <div class='row column_popup'>
          <span class='span_table'>Il n'existe pas de résultat à votre recherche.</span>
          <span class='span_table'>Si vous le souhaitez vous pouvez modifer votre recherche ou ajouter un nouveau
            correspondant externe.</span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div id="parent" class="col s8 m12 l12">
    <div class="logo-chu"><img class="logo-chu" src="/img/logo-chu.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</footer>





{% elseif int is empty or ext is empty %}
<main>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div id="appear">
      <div class="container tableau">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs">



              {% if  int is empty %}
              <li class="tab col s12 m6 l6"><a href="#interne">Interne ({{nb_int}})</a></li>
              <li class="tab col s12 m6 l6"><a href="#externe" class="active">Externe ({{nb_ext}})</a></li>
              {% else %}
              <li class="tab col s12 m6 l6"><a href="#interne">Interne ({{nb_int}})</a></li>
              <li class="tab col s12 m6 l6"><a href="#externe">Externe ({{nb_ext}})</a></li>
              {% endif %}


            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container tableau">
        <div class="row card">
          <div id="interne" class="col s12">
            {% if int is empty %}
            <span class='span_table'>Il n'existe pas d'interne correspondant à votre recherche.</span>

            {% else %}
            <div class="row">
              <table id="tabledata2" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">

                <thead class="tabheader">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="column1">Civilité</th>
                    <th class="column2">Nom</th>
                    <th class="column3">Prénom</th>
                    <th class="column4">Nom marital</th>
                    <th class="column5">Spécialité</th>
                    <th class="column6">Adresse</th>
                    <th class="column6">Commune</th>
                    <th class="column6">Code postal</th>
                    <th class="column6">Pays</th>
                    <th class="column6">RPPS</th>
                    <th class="column6">Profil</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container tableau">
        <div class="row card">
          <div id="externe" class="col s12">
            {% if ext is empty %}
            <span class='span_table'>Il n'existe pas d'externe correspondant à votre recherche.</span>

            {% else %}
            
            <div class="row">
              <table id="tabledata" class="display nowrap highlight" style="width:100%">

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="column1">Civilité</th>
                    <th class="column2">Nom</th>
                    <th class="column3">Prénom</th>
                    <th class="column4">Nom marital</th>
                    <th class="column5">Spécialité</th>
                    <th class="column6">Adresse</th>
                    <th class="column7">Commune</th>
                    <th class="column8">Code postal</th>
                    <th class="column9">Pays</th>
                    <th class="column10">RPPS</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="extern_body">
                  {% for key in ext %}
                  
                    {% if key.annulation == 'T'  %}
                      {% if key.corrMat != focus %}
                      <tr class="fondtr tr_tab" data-target="{{ path('recherche_edit', {id: key.corrMat})}}">
                      {% else %}
                      <tr class="fondtr tr_tab" data-target="{{ path('recherche_edit', {id: key.corrMat})}}" style="font-weight : bold">
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if key.medTitre == 'Mme' or key.medTitre == 'MME'%}
                      <td class="column1" title="FEMININ ANNULE"><img class="feminin" src="/img/signe-feminin-annule.png">
                        <p class="sort">1</p>
                      </td>
                      {% elseif key.medTitre == 'M'%}
                      <td class="column1" title="MASCULIN ANNULE"><img class="masculin" src="/img/signe-masculin-annule.png">
                        <p class="sort">2</p>
                      </td>
                      {% else %}
                      <td class="column1" title="AUTRE ANNULE"><img class="indifferent" src="/img/signe-medical-annule.png">
                        <p class="sort">0</p>
                      </td>
                      {% endif %}
                    
                    {% else %}
                      {% if key.corrMat != focus %}
                      <tr  class="tr_tab" data-target="{{ path('recherche_edit', {id: key.corrMat})}}">
                      {% else %}
                      <tr  class="tr_tab" data-target="{{ path('recherche_edit', {id: key.corrMat})}}" style="font-weight : bold">
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if key.medTitre == 'Mme' or key.medTitre %}
                      <td class="column1" title="FEMININ"><img class="feminin" src="/img/signe-feminin.png">
                        <p class="sort">1</p>
                      </td>
                      {% elseif key.medTitre == 'M'%}
                      <td class="column1" title="MASCULIN"><img class="masculin" src="/img/signe-masculin.png">
                        <p class="sort">2</p>
                      </td>
                      {% else %}
                      <td class="column1" title="AUTRE"><img class="indifferent" src="/img/signe-medical.png">
                        <p class="sort">0</p>
                      </td>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                      <td class="column2" title="{{ key.medNom  }}">{{ key.medNom }}</td>
                      <td class="column3" title="{{ key.medPren}}">{{ key.medPren }}</td>
                      <td class="column4" title="{{ key.mednomEp}}">{{ key.mednomEp }}</td>
                      <td class="column5" title="{{ key.medSpec }}">{{ key.medSpec }}</td>
                      <td class="column6" title="{{ key.medadrL1}}">{{ key.medadrL1 }}</td>
                      <td class="column7" title="{{ key.medadrCo }}">{{ key.medadrCo }}</td>
                      <td class="column8" title="{{ key.medadrCp }}">{{ key.medadrCp }}</td>
                      <td class="column9" title="{{ key.medadrPays }}">{{ key.medadrPays }}</td>
                      <td class="column10" title="{{ key.rpps }}">{{ key.rpps}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  

                  {% endfor %}

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
  <section class="col s12">
    <div id="buttons" class="excel"></div>
    <p class="export">Exporter vers :</p>
    
  </section>
  {% endif %}
</main>
<img class="responsive-img" src="/img/fond-recherche.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100%">



{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

This is my form

```
    class CorrMedExtType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('corrMaitre', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('corrMatMaitre', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medTitre', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medcpltTitre' , ChoiceType::class, ['required'=>false,
                'choices' =>[
                    ''=>'',
                    'LA DIETETICIENNE'=>'LA DIETETICIENNE',
                    'LA PUERICULTRICE'=>'LA PUERICULTRICE',
                    'LA SAGE FEMME'=>'LA SAGE FEMME',
                    'L\'ASSISTANTE SOCIALE'=>'L\'ASSISTANTE SOCIALE',
                    'LE DOCTEUR'=> 'LE DOCTEUR',
                ]
                    
                ])
            ->add('medNom', TextType::class,['required'=>false])
            ->add('medPren', TextType::class,['required'=>false])
            ->add('mednomEp', TextType::class,['required'=>false])
            ->add('medadrL1', TextType::class,['required'=>false])
            ->add('medadrL2', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medadrLoc', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medSpec', ChoiceType::class,
            [   'required'=>false,
                'choices' =>[
                    ''=>'',
                    'BIOLOGIE'  =>'B05_BIOLOGIE',
                    'CANCEROLOGIE'    =>'M06_CANCEROLOGIE',
                    'MEDECINE GENERALE'=>'M61_MEDECINE GENERALE',
                    'MEDECINE INTERNE'=>'M25_MEDECINE INTERNE',
                    'MEDECINE NUCLEAIRE'=>'M27_MEDECINE NUCLEAIRE',
                    
            ]
                
            ])
            ->add('medadrCp')
            ->add('medadrCo')
            ->add('medadrPays', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medSexe', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('medCmt', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('annulation', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('telListRouge', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('adresseelectr', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('gdatecreation', DateType::class,['required'=>false, 'widget'=>'single_text'])
            ->add('gdatemodificat', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('grdnannuaire', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('identifiantFt', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('creePar', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('matricule100', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('rpps', NumberType::class, ['required'=>false])
            ->add('adresseApicrypt', EmailType::class,['required'=>false])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => CorrMedExt::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my repository

```
    class CorrMedExtRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, CorrMedExt::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return CorrMedExt[] Returns an array of CorrMedExt objects
    //  */
    
    
    public function Recherche($prenom,$nom,$nomMarital,$cpltTitre,$specialite,$adresse,$commune,$cp,$apicrypt,$rpps,$datecrea,$table)
    {
        //Si tous les champs sont vides, on recherche les contacts fait à la date du jour
        if ($prenom == NULL && $nom== NULL && $nomMarital== NULL 
            && $cpltTitre== NULL && $specialite== NULL && $adresse== NULL && $commune== NULL && $cp== NULL 
            && $apicrypt== NULL  && $rpps == NULL && $datecrea == NULL 
            && $prenom=='' && $nom=='' && $nomMarital=='' 
            && $cpltTitre=='' && $specialite =='' && $adresse =='' && $commune =='' && $cp =='' && $apicrypt  =='' && $rpps =='' && $datecrea ==''){
                
                $dateTime = new \DateTime('today');
                return $this->createQueryBuilder('table')
                    ->Where('table.gdatecreation = :date')
                    ->setParameter('date', $dateTime)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();
            }
        //Sinon on vérifie chaque champs
        else {
            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('table');
            if($prenom != NULL && $prenom !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medPren like :prenom');
                $query->setParameter('prenom', '%'.$prenom.'%');
            }
    
            if ($nom != NULL && $nom !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medNom like :nom');
                $query->setParameter('nom', '%'.$nom.'%');
            }

            if ($nomMarital != NULL && $nomMarital !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.mednomEp like :nomEp');
                $query->setParameter('nomEp', '%'.$nomMarital.'%');
            }
    
            if($cpltTitre != NULL && $cpltTitre !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medcpltTitre like :cpltTitre');
                $query->setParameter('cpltTitre', '%'.$cpltTitre.'%');
            }
    
            if($specialite != NULL && $specialite !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medSpec like :spec');
                $query->setParameter('spec', '%'.$specialite.'%');
            }

            if($adresse != NULL && $adresse !=''){
                $query->andWhere('(table.medadrL1 like :adr or table.medadrL2 like :adr)');
                $query->setParameter('adr', '%'.$adresse.'%');
            }
    
            if($commune != NULL && $commune !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medadrCo like :commune');
                $query->setParameter('commune', '%'.$commune.'%');
            }
    
            if($cp != NULL && $cp !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.medadrCp like :cp');
                $query->setParameter('cp', '%'.$cp.'%');
            }
    
            if($apicrypt != NULL && $apicrypt !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.adresseApicrypt like :adresseApicrypt');
                $query->setParameter('$adresseApicrypt', '%'.$apicrypt.'%');
            }
    
            if($rpps != NULL && $rpps !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.rpps like :rpps');
                $query->setParameter('rpps', '%'.$rpps.'%');
            }

            if($datecrea != NULL && $datecrea !=''){
                $query->andWhere('table.gdatecreation = :date');
                $query->setParameter('date',$datecrea);
            }
                        

            return $query->getQuery()
                ->execute();
        }
    }

}
```

And my .js

```
    /RESET/
$(document).ready(function() {
  adCompleted();
  idCompleted();
  reCompleted();
  //Fonction pour réinitialiser le formulaire de recherche
  $('button:reset').click(function(){
    //RAZ des champs textes et dates
    $('#corr_med_ext_medNom').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_medPren').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_mednomEp').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_adresseApicrypt').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_rpps').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_medadrL1').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_medadrCo').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_medadrCp').attr('value','');
    $('#corr_med_ext_gdatecreation').attr('value','');

    //RAZ des select
    $('option',$('#corr_med_ext_medcpltTitre')).each(function(element){
      $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
    });
    $('option',$('#corr_med_ext_medSpec')).each(function(element){
      $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
    });
    idCompleted();
    reCompleted();
    adCompleted();
    //Refresh champs
    M.updateTextFields();
    $('#showid').html('0');
    $('#showad').html('0');
    $('#showre').html('0');
  })
});

//sidenav collapse
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});

//tab
setTimeout(function(){ 
  //table width
  var table = $('#tabledata').removeAttr('style').DataTable( {
      scrollX:true,
      bPaginate:false,
      bInfo:false,
      bFilter:false,
      orderClasses:false,
  } );
  //export
  var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
    buttons: [
      'excelHtml5',
   ]
}).container().appendTo($('#buttons'));
  document.getElementsByClassName("dt-button")[0].id="excel_button";
  var button_excel = document.getElementById('excel_button');
  button_excel.innerHTML="";
}, 20);
```

Comment: so basically you want the button to submit the data to 2 endpoints at once, and get two sets of results, is that correct? I'm not sure it was 100% clear how it's supposed to work. But if that's correct then, in that case, you can use Javascript to achieve it (assuming the forms are both submitted via AJAX, of course).

Comment: Just use one form.  It's easy enough to combine two form types into one form in the controller.

Comment: For more details,I added my controller where my form is linked to @ADyson

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't explain anything about your other results. Do they come from separate controller action?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, no they are in the same controller. And yes I want the button to submit the data of fromExterne and formInterne in their respective tabs of the table

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I tried to ask if it came from a separation action function? It can be in any controller, or the same one - it's irrelevant. You need to show us that, and show the HTML form, and any associated Javascript, so we can understand better how you might merge the functionality.

Comment: @ADyson I added all the code link to my form